# How shutdown the computer from console with option to cancel?

Tags: gnome, shutdown, console, gnome-session

I want close the gnome session and shutdown the computer when the downloads finish but I want to show the shutdown window to can cancel it in some cases.
I use: `gnome-session-quit --power-off --force` but this doesn't work when the screen is in suspend mode. Is this a bug or the normal behavior? In Gnome 2 this worked well even the screen is off.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can type `shutdown --help` in a terminal to see various options

> ```
> shutdown --help
> Usage: shutdown [OPTION]... TIME [MESSAGE]
> Bring the system down.
>
> Options:
>   -r                          reboot after shutdown
>   -h                          halt or power off after shutdown
>   -H                          halt after shutdown (implies -h)
>   -P                          power off after shutdown (implies -h)
>   -c                          cancel a running shutdown
>   -k                          only send warnings, don't shutdown
>   -q, --quiet                 reduce output to errors only
>   -v, --verbose               increase output to include informational messages
>       --help                  display this help and exit
>       --version               output version information and exit
> ```
>
> TIME may have different formats, the most common is simply the word
>   'now' which will bring the system down immediately.  Other valid
>   formats are +m, where m is the number of minutes to wait until
>   shutting down and hh:mm which specifies the time on the 24hr clock.
>
> Logged in users are warned by a message sent to their terminal, you
>   may include an optional MESSAGE included with this.  Messages can be
>   sent without actually bringing the system down by using the -k option.
>
> If TIME is given, the command will remain in the foreground until the
>   shutdown occurs.  It can be cancelled by Control-C, or by another user
>   using the -c option.
>
> The system is brought down into maintenance (single-user) mode by
>   default, you can change this with either the -r or -h option which
>   specify a reboot or system halt respectively.  The -h option can be
>   further modified with -H or -P to specify whether to halt the system,
>   or to power it off afterwards.  The default is left up to the shutdown
>   scripts.

to make run you will need `sudo shutdown now` for instance will shut the computer down right away.

hope this helps.

Comment: ok, but "_...I want to show the shutdown window to can cancel it in some cases._" The shutdown command (_I knew it_) shows nothing to alert the user of the shutdown.

Comment: there is this that is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526329/possible-to-abort-shutdown-on-linux  i was just checking but other than this i haven't seen of a gui that does this! let me know if you find one  :-) cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm pretty sure that this is a gnome bug with `gnome-session-quit`.
While they solve it I've created a script to do this:

```
yad --text-info --title LFTP --text='<b>El sistema procederá a apagarse en unos segundos...</b>' --image=/home/simon/.local/share/icons/lftp.png --image-on-top --timeout=10 --timeout-indicator=bottom --on-top --center --button=gtk-cancel:0 --window-icon=/home/simon/.local/share/icons/lftp.png || sudo shutdown -h now
```

I use [yad](http://code.google.com/p/yad/) (*a fork of Zenity*) to show the alert.

Comment: hmmm this looks interesting i play with this later :-)